# How can I display actual public/private key of key pair I just generated with gpg?

Tags: key, gnupg

I just created a key-pair locally on my linux machine with the gpg command:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

Then I tried to display the information about my key-pair with the gpg command:

```
 gpg --list-keys
```

The long alpha-numeric number outputed by the above command is (from what I understand from reading the doc), the fingerprint of the public key of the pair, which is the result of applying a hash function on the public key.

1. Is this correct?
2. How can I see the actual public and private keys of the pair I generated?
   I know this isn't directly useful for encrypting or signing, I'm just curious to see what they look like

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to see the actual keys, use the "export" commands (`--export` and `--export-secret-keys`). You can specify which key to output by passing it the fingerprint of the key, you want to see.

Let's say you have a key with the fingerprint FINGERPRINT. Then you would export the public key to stdout via

```
gpg --export FINGERPRINT
```

At least in my version and configuration of bash, this does not produce readable output because of encoding (i guess). To get a more readable output, you may export the key to a file via the output option. As stated in the manual (`man gpg`) the command syntax is as follows:

```
gpg [--homedir dir] [--options file] [options] command [args]
```

So if you want to export to let's say your home directory into a file MyPubKey.txt you can use this command:

```
gpg --ouput ~/MyPubKey.txt --export FINGERPRINT
```

The same is valid for your private key, you just have to use `--export-secret-key` instead of `--export`. But keep in mind, that this poses a possible security risk. If you export your private key to an insecure (non-encrypted, accessible) storage device (a thumb stick for instance), your private key may well be retrievable, even if you have deleted it!

Answer (score 1):

about your questions:

1. Yes, that is correct;
2. You can use `gpg --list-keys` or `gpg -k` to list all your keys. Also, you can use `gpg --list-secret-keys` (`pub` means public keys, while `sec` means secret [private] keys).